# HTTP Error 503 on Win2k8 when browsing to the root of an ASP.NET application using HTTPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, 503-error

I use IIS7 on a win2k8 server machine (the problem persists both for win2k8 and win2k8 R2).

I have an ASP.NET application with directory browsing enabled. When I browse to it using http I can see the directory contents just fine. When, however, I browse to it using https - I get HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I do not have such problem on win2k3 server, so this is something particular to win2k8 servers, but what?

**EDIT1**

Here is the contents of httperr1.log:

```
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2011-04-12 08:04:38
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2011-04-12 08:04:38 172.30.2.68 55798 172.30.2.67 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico 404 - NotFound -
2011-04-12 08:04:38 172.30.2.68 55799 172.30.2.67 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico 404 - NotFound -
2011-04-12 08:04:41 172.30.2.68 55800 172.30.2.67 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico 404 - NotFound -
2011-04-12 08:49:46 172.30.2.68 57224 172.30.2.67 443 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2011-04-12 09:43:05 172.30.2.68 58571 172.30.2.67 443 HTTP/1.1 POST /CAServer/Service.svc - - Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue -
2011-04-13 08:08:54 ::1%0 49591 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:09:43 ::1%0 49593 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:09:45 ::1%0 49598 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:09:45 ::1%0 49599 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:09:58 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49605 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:13:14 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49638 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:13:16 172.30.2.68 62531 172.30.2.67 443 HTTP/1.1 POST /CAServer/Service.svc 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:14:16 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49643 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:14:17 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49644 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:14:17 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49645 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:14:48 172.30.2.68 62645 172.30.2.67 443 HTTP/1.1 POST /CAServer/Service.svc 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:15:39 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49648 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer/Service.svc 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:17:38 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49650 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:14 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49670 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:15 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49671 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:15 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49672 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:17 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49673 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:17 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49674 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:19 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49675 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 08:33:19 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 49676 fe80::6d0f:30e:a216:df24%11 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2011-04-13 08:57:33
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2011-04-13 08:57:33 ::1%0 49271 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
2011-04-13 14:05:33 ::1%0 49293 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /CAServer 503 - N/A -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a standard html page also fail?  I would double check that the cert is correct and that the binding in another site isn't taking precedence.

Also, if you check the IIS logs, it will confirm that the correct site is receiving the request, and if you check the sub-status code, it will give further details on the specifics of the 503.

Comment: No, browsing to the same url using http works. Replace http with https and boom - 503. BTW, I have attached http.sys log - as you can see there is no sub-status code.

Comment: Also, browsing to the site url using https works - one sees the IIS7 welcome logo.

Comment: I see that it's using IPv6 to connect.  What happens if you test with https://your-IPv4ip/ to ensure that it's visiting over ipv4?  Or, add an http binding for ipv6.  What's probably happening is that your ipv4 https binding isn't being used, but there must be a wildcard https binding on your default web site which is what is catching this directory listing request.

Comment: How can I say in the binding that I am interested in IPv4, but not IPv6?

Comment: You are a genius. I have disabled IPv6 entirely and suddenly it works. I wonder what is next, after all I cannot make the installer disable IPv6. I have to solve it somehow without disabling IPv6. Any ideas?

Comment: I have restored back IPv6 and it still works. I guess this has fixed some internal state of God knows what. Anyway, it all works now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that you narrowed it down to IPv6!  I suspect that it's a priority thing where IPv6 will kick back in after a bit, so I wouldn't consider it solved yet.  What you should be able to do is take the IPv6 IP addresses from the log above and create https bindings for them.  Then both ipv4 and ipv6 will bind correctly to the correct site.